# Can Java run directly on hardware?

Tags: java

Can Java run directly on hardware (assuming there's enough memory to include the necessary JRE/JVM? If it can, how does System.out.println work? I'd think there's nowhere for that output to go if it's all just on a cpu.

Comment: If you are implementing the JVM, then you are essentially *not* running Java on pure hardware, you are using the JVM as your OS.

Comment: @Robert Columbia I see that now. I may be visualizing this wrong, but if all that's there is Java and the JVM (no screen, or anything right?) where does System.out.println output go?

Comment: Wherever your implementation of the JVM tells it to go.

Comment: @Robert Columbia Would it typically just drop the call and do nothing with it, or crash? I mean if we use one of the "standard" implementations I could download from Oracle for Windows or something.

Comment: That is one of the basic functions of an OS. Your OS should define where standard output goes, or how to determine (based on OS configuration) where it should go. It can go anywhere - to a console, a text-to-speech converter hooked up to a speaker, to a modem, to a line printer, or straight to the bit bucket. Do you know anything about OS architecture?

Comment: The whole point of Java as a technology is that it can run anywhere that somebody's programmed a virtual machine. If it's possible to program a virtual machine on a particular platform, then the answer is "yes", Java can run on it.

Comment: `System.out` typically refers to the same "standard output" destination as C's `stdout`. If there is a C library or a JVM implementation for a system, then they should include a definition of where standard output goes. If there is no C library and no JVM, then you're in the realm of **operating system programming** or even **computer engineering**, and if you want a "standard output" you'll have to read books or take classes on those subjects until you can build your own "standard output" from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly on hardware? I am assuming you mean to ask if Java can run on a micro-controller? The answer is yes. The JVM is a virtual machine which is essentially its own operating system. The JVM was designed to do exactly what your wondering about. The JVM's two primary functions are to allow Java programs to run on any device or operating system, "Write once, run anywhere" and to optimize memory solutions.

To answer your second question. In order to visually see the output of a System.out.println() call one would simply need to provide the micro-controller with a screen. However, in theory the code would still execute without you seeing it being displayed. So one could write a Java applet that prints "hello world" and then load it onto a micro-controller and run it but that's just silly.

EDIT: I assumed you were not asking: "Can you program a micro-controller with Java" Silly of me, the answer is yes you certainly can; however, you wouldn't want too because the JVM is rather large and it would take up a lot of space. That being said, if you are interested take a look at: the STM32 Java-ready micro-controllers or the Renesas RX. Also, you could run a gutted JVM using uJ or NonvoVM.

Comment: Note that there is not simply "The JVM". You would have to obtain (or write) an *implementation* of the JVM for your particular microcontroller. That implementation would specify how to locate and communicate with the screen or other output device of that microcontroller.

Comment: @Haw Exp The output is just 1's and 0's hi voltages and low voltages on the hardware level. Pulses can be sent down wires even if those pulses are not being used by some peripheral device. EDIT: Hawk asked another question after Columbia's response here but he deleted it. I swear I am not answering phantom questions lol. I will keep my response in case he is interested.

Comment: Would a JVM made for a microcontroller have a different class library? Or does it include the same library as included for standard PCs? I'm asking because I'm confused as to how microcontroller JVMs would handle I/O methods like System.out.println in the case of there not being an output device. Edit: Never mind, thanks @Rob!

Comment: I have one more question, haha. What about things like JavaFX? Are some classes not included in microcontroller JVMs?

Comment: @ Haw Exp I will expand my answer because it will be to long for the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, due to the JVM and write once run anywhere feature in java, the code is not ran directly on the hardware but within the JVM... THE JVM essentially acts as a middle man between different hardware/OS...if you look to accomplish this then take a look at C++